# Generics and ArrayLists

Tags: generics, arraylist, struts2

I have this `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Fruits> fruitList = Fruits.getNames();
```

I now want to print out, say the value in index 2 of the arrayList. 
I tried the following in my method

```
public ArrayList<Fruits> getFruitList(){
    fruitList = fruitList.get(2);
    return fruitList;
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following error

```
incompatible types
required: ArrayList<Fruits>  
found: Fruits
```

This method is in a Struts2 action class, I am basically sending `fruitList` to a jsp page.
The following works without a problem, it returns the entire arraylist

```
public ArrayList<Fruits> getFruitList(){
    return fruitList;
}
```

However what I want is just the value from a particular index. Hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: You should define a type that you want to access using a single property.

Answer (score 0):

Since `fruitList` is of type `ArrayList<Fruits>`, the value of `fruitList.get(2)` will be of type `Fruits`. You cannot assign that back to `fruidList` and you cannot return it from a method of type `ArrayList<Fruits>`. If you want to return a single element of `fruitList`, you can simply declare your method to return a `Fruits` value, not an `ArrayList<Fruits>`. It should also have a different name:

```
public Fruits getFruitAt(int index){
    return fruitList.get(index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ted, I still have a problem though. How do I get to see the out in the jsp page? As it is the code in the jsp is as follow:

    <s:property value = "fruitList" />  

and there is no output in the jsp page.

Comment: @Sor - If you want to display a single value, then why would the property value be `"fruitList"`? Do you want to display a single value or do you want to display a readable string representing the entire array contents?

Comment: To use indexed property access this method could be used, but OGNL knows how to get an element of the list by the index without this method.